# Jetty datasource with Atomikos UserTransaction

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, jetty, jta, atomikos

I have two datasources in my Web application (principalDB and backupDB) on two Postgresql DBs, and a web container managed transaction manager (with Atomikos) for them. Spring FW and Hibernate are my building blocks for the application. The problem I am running into is that Jetty 6.1.3 web container does not seem to load the app specific  WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml that declares the resources so I am getting an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException; remaining name 'env/jdbc/principalDB'
 at org.mortbay.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:634)
 at org.mortbay.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:665)
 at org.mortbay.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:680)
 at org.mortbay.naming.java.javaRootURLContext.lookup(javaRootURLContext.java:112)
 at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:351)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:88)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:153)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:200)
 at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:186)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1368)
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
 ... 43 more
```

Here is how I configured the two datasources

1. in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` I have declared the two resources with resource-ref as:

   ```
   <resource-ref>
    <description>The principal datasource</description>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/principalDB</res-ref-name>
   </resource-ref>
   <resource-ref>
    <description>The backup datasource</description>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/backupDB</res-ref-name>
   </resource-ref>
   ```
2. in the `WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml` I have

   ```
   <New id="principalDB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
   <Arg><Ref id="wac"/></Arg>
     <Arg>jdbc/principalDB</Arg>
     <Arg>
       <New class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.NonXADataSourceBean">
         <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3ConnectionPool</Set>
         <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
         <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
         <Set name="DatabaseName">first</Set>
         <Set name="Url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/first</Set>
         <Set name="user">test</Set>
         <Set name="password">password</Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </New>

   <New id="backupDB" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
   <Arg><Ref id="wac"/></Arg>
     <Arg>jdbc/backupDB</Arg>
     <Arg>
       <New class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.NonXADataSourceBean">
         <Set name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3ConnectionPool</Set>
         <Set name="ServerName">localhost</Set>
         <Set name="PortNumber">5432</Set>
         <Set name="DatabaseName">second</Set>
         <Set name="Url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/second</Set>
         <Set name="user">testSec</Set>
         <Set name="password">password</Set>
       </New>
     </Arg>
   </New>
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Make **sure** you followed *Step 1* and *Step 2* of http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Atomikos (assuming you are using Atomikos 3.3 and onwards).

Then, for the *Step 3*, pay a special attention to this note:

> as the `NonXADataSourceBean` uses **only** the class name and url of a `java.sql.Driver`, you can use it with any database providing a JDBC driver.

So your current setup contains too much things but, more important, the driver class name looks wrong, it should be `org.postgresql.Driver`.

But the PostgreSQL JDBC driver does support `XADatasource` (with the `org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource` implementation) so I'd rather configure a `AtomikosDataSourceBean` (the first option of *Step 3*). Something like that:

```
<New id="mydatasource" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
  <Arg><Ref id='wac'/></Arg>
  <Arg>jdbc/mydatasource</Arg>
  <Arg>
    <New class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean">
      <Set name="minPoolSize">2</Set>
      <Set name="maxPoolSize">20</Set>
      <Set name="xaDataSourceClassName">org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</Set>
      <Set name="xaProperties">
        <New class="java.util.Properties">
          <Call name="setProperty"><Arg>databaseName</Arg><Arg>testdb</Arg></Call>
          <Call name="setProperty"><Arg>serverName</Arg><Arg>localhost</Arg></Call>
          <Call name="setProperty"><Arg>portNumber</Arg><Arg>5432</Arg></Call>
          <Call name="setProperty"><Arg>user</Arg><Arg>test</Arg></Call>
          <Call name="setProperty"><Arg>password</Arg><Arg>p4ssw0rd</Arg>/Call>
        </New>
      </Set>
      <Set name="UniqueResourceName">mydatasource</Set>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>
```

Comment: It seems that even when my jetty-plus.xml is a broken XML (like having an unclosed '/Call>' tag), I am getting the very same exception as if the configuration file is completely ignored by Jetty. 
I copy the configuration from the jetty-plus.xml into the [jetty]/etc/jetty.xml and correct the XML the datasources are still not registered with JNDI.

Comment: @peter Hard to say anything without seeing what you're doing. But these instructions http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JNDI definitely work.